# How to Access unlabeled JSON array elements in Python?

Tags: python, json

Working on a small project that returns JSON on API call. However, I seem to be unable to obtain the values from the string. I can print the JSON but cannot seem to obtain individual elements.

I have tried json.loads() to ensure I am operating on a JSON object. To access the value associated with the "faceId" key, I tried the following but to no avail:

```
data = response.read()
dataStream = json.dumps(data)
faceIdentification = dataStream[0]['faceId']
```

I also attempted:

```
faceIdentification = dataStream['faceId']
```

and

```
faceIdentification = dataStream['faceId'][0]
```

I also tried directly operating on the JSON received but no luck.
The JSON I want to obtain the faceId's value from is:

```
[{"faceId":"52f388ad-6789-4657-af4d-0dc308cc9aaa","faceRectangle":{"top":237,"left":204,"width":226,"height":226}}]
```

Comment: you means `json.loads()` not `json.dumps()`

Comment: Ah yes, that was the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a string format. To turn it into Python data structures, you "load" it:

```
data = response.read()
dataStream = json.loads(data)
```

Now `dataStream` is a list of dictionaries. The first of it is `dataStream[0]`, and the 'faceId' element of it is `dataStream[0]['faceId']`.

Comment: Thank you for that. The error was the "dump" section of the code

Answer (score 0):

1) Accessing a json array obtained as a response for a GET request.

```
[{"symbol":"EURUSD","bid":1.13859,"ask":1.13911,"price":1.13885,"timestamp":1541215930}]

    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    bid = json_data[0]['bid']
    ask = json_data[0]['ask']
    price = json_data[0]['price']
    timestamp = json_data[0]['timestamp']
```

2) Accessing a simple json without having an array as follows.

```
{"rates":{"EURUSD":{"rate":1.138789,"timestamp":1541224588014}},"code":200}

json_data = json.loads(response.text)
result = json_data['rates']['EURUSD']
rate = json_data['rates']['EURUSD']['rate']
timestamp = json_data['rates']['EURUSD']['timestamp']
code = json_data['code']
```